# How to recreate Grafana kNative dashboards in Google Cloud

Tags: prometheus, grafana, google-cloud-monitoring, knative

I'm using the kNative Observability plugin which installs Prometheus and Grafana on my Google Kubernetes Engine cluster.

There are two issues:

1. In the newest versions on kNative, the plugin is deprecated
2. I see that the plugin saves logs within the Prometheus pod (my best guess) and sometimes it crashes under high load.

Is there a way to recreate the Grafana dashboards in Google Cloud Monitoring? Maybe a better question is, would there be a way to get the kNative logs logged by Prometheus into Google Cloud's environment?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Prometheus metrics exported to Cloud Monitoring using the [sidecar](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/prometheus) built for that purpose.

Logs are going to be harder - you need to figure out a way to reconfigure the plugin to send logs to stdout and/or stderr to get the cluster logging agent to pick them up and ingest them into Cloud Logging.  Another option would be to build a sidecar container explicitly for that purpose.